# Make Image Container Responsive

Tags: responsive-design

I have 3 image container aligned horizontal however I can't seem to make it responsive. When screen size are smaller, the box changed to a smaller size and the text were out of place. I would like the container align vertically when screen size are small and container to have a fixed shape and the text to stay together with the container.

Here is my code:

```css
.images-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: -30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imgwide {
  width: 31.3%;
  height: 450px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgwide:hover {
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0.99);
}

.arrow {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 380px;
  bottom: 9px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 700px;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 48px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  bottom: 25px;
}

.bottom-left2 {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 700px;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 521px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.bottom-left3 {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 700px;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 991px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-container">
  <div class="imgwide" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), url('assets/vr.jpeg');background-size: 600px; background-position: center;" onclick="window.open('', '_blank')"></div>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <div class="bottom-left"> VR Tour<i class="arrow right"></i></div>
  </a>
  <div class="imgwide" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), url('');background-size: 600px;" onclick="window.open('', '_blank')"></div>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <div class="bottom-left2">Trails<i class="arrow right"></i></div>
  </a>
  <div class="imgwide" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), url('');background-size: 600px; background-position: center;" onclick="window.open('', '_blank')"></div>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <div class="bottom-left3">Grandfathers Road<i class="arrow right"></i></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: use media queries

Comment: post the code you tried - this is how this site works

Comment: @anon https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries <- lengthy breakdown of how they work. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp <- functional examples for you to study and guide you

Comment: Please edit this code to your question and don't just post it at comment. You can edit questions even after posting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working properly because the way you are using `position` is wrong.

> you don't need to make three different classes for your titles just make one class and set it's `position` to `absolute` and `bottom:0;`, then instead of setting `position: relative;` to `.images-container` set it to `.imgwide`, after this the titles should stick to bottom of the items

I made for you hope it helps, also made some changes to make it cleaner:)

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.images-container .img')].forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open(this.children[0].href, '_blank');
  });
});
```

```css
.images-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  min-width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 2px 6px 2px;
  background-position: center !important;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* change images here */

.img:nth-child(1) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)), url('https://source.unsplash.com/ndN00KmbJ1c/640x400');
}

.img:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)), url('https://source.unsplash.com/mBQIfKlvowM/640x400');
}

.img:nth-child(3) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)), url('https://source.unsplash.com/y2azHvupCVo/640x400');
}

.img:hover {
  transform: scale(0.99);
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  --title-color: #ffffff;
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-size: max(16px, 1.2vw);
  bottom: 0;
}

.title::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid var(--title-color);
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 0 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .images-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .img {
    width: 95%;
    height: 330px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: max(16px, 1.5vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images-container">
  <div class="img">
    <a href="https://virtualtour.eurasians.org.sg/ehg/" target="_blank">
      <div class="title">Eurasian Heritage Gallery VR Tour</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a href="https://pa-heritage-trails.web.app/overview.html" target="_blank">
      <div class="title">Self-Guided Heritage Trails</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a href="https://explore-grandfather-road.web.app/" target="_blank">
      <div class="title">Let's Explore Our <br>Grandfathers Road</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

...UPDATED...

That's pretty simple, you can do that with `margin`.
example attached

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.images-container .img')].forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open(this.children[0].href, '_blank');
  });
});
```

```css
.head-title {
  border-left: 5px red solid;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.images-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.images-container .holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  min-width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 2px 6px 2px;
  background-position: center !important;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* change images here */

.img:nth-child(1) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)), url('https://source.unsplash.com/ndN00KmbJ1c/640x400');
}

.img:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)), url('https://source.unsplash.com/mBQIfKlvowM/640x400');
}

.img:nth-child(3) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)), url('https://source.unsplash.com/y2azHvupCVo/640x400');
}

.img:hover {
  transform: scale(0.99);
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  --title-color: #ffffff;
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-size: max(16px, 1.2vw);
  bottom: 0;
}

.title::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid var(--title-color);
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 0 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .head-title {
    margin: 5px 1%;
  }
  .images-container .holder {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .img {
    width: 98%;
    height: 390px;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: max(16px, 1.5vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images-container">
  <div>
    <h2 class="head-title">Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://virtualtour.eurasians.org.sg/ehg/" target="_blank">
        <div class="title">Eurasian Heritage Gallery VR Tour</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://pa-heritage-trails.web.app/overview.html" target="_blank">
        <div class="title">Self-Guided Heritage Trails</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://explore-grandfather-road.web.app/" target="_blank">
        <div class="title">Let's Explore Our <br>Grandfathers Road</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="images-container">
  <div>
    <h2 class="head-title">Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://explore-grandfather-road.web.app/" target="_blank">
        <div class="title">Let's Explore Our <br>Grandfathers Road</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://virtualtour.eurasians.org.sg/ehg/" target="_blank">
        <div class="title">Eurasian Heritage Gallery VR Tour</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much this helped alot! Quick question, how do i align the container with the header title? Do i have to change the sizing of the container so that the website won't expand?

Comment: And how do i change the sizing of the container?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your first question what do you mean by header title? and about your second question, you can change the size of the container by changing `width` property in `.images-container {width:100%;}`, also if you want to make the container taller or shorter you must change the `height` property in `.img {height:350px;}`

Comment: @Alizera Thank You! I've attached an image on to the question regarding the first question, let me know what you think.

Comment: @anon Anytime, The answer has been updated and added an example! you should play with `margin` property in `.head-title{}` and  `width` and `margin` property in `.img{}` until you get the ideal result. I need to add something, I'm not very  familiar with stackoverflow rules but I think if you have another question you must open a new one not keep editing the current one, goodluck :)